# Ventas Periodo Actual y Ventas Periodo Año Anterior SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un DataWareHouse al que le tengo que agregar nuevas columnas con las ventas del mismo periodo pero del año anterior. El periodo está como `varchar`.

Lo que hice en un principio, es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT 
VM1.ValorNetoUSD AS USD, 
VM1.IdPeriodo AS Periodo, 
VM2.ValorNetoUSD AS USDAA, 
VM2.IdPeriodo AS PeriodoAA
FROM AT2020_DWH.dbo.FctVentaMensual AS VM1
INNER JOIN AT2020_DWH.dbo.FctVentaMensual AS VM2
ON CONVERT(date, LEFT(VM1.IdPeriodo, 2)+'/01/'+RIGHT(VM1.IdPeriodo, 4)) = 
DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CONVERT(date, LEFT(VM2.IdPeriodo, 2)+'/01/'+RIGHT(VM2.IdPeriodo, 4)))
;
```

Esto me devuelve registros duplicados del lado de las ventas actuales. Probé cambiando el tipo de JOIN a LEFT pero el resultado es el mismo.

Qué debería corregir para obtener lo que busco?

Desde ya, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: los datos almacenados en ´IdPeriodo´ que formato tienen. Si puedes poner un ejemplo por favor. Ej. DD-MM-YYYY o DD/MM/YYYY o DDMMYYYY.

Comment: IdPeriodo es un campo varchar. Esta como 012007. Por eso la conversión que hago a tipo DATE, para poder usar las funciones de fecha (DATEADD).

Comment: Cambio un poco el planteo inicial para ver si ayuda. En una tabla donde tengo 2 columnas, IdPeriodo (varchar, ejemplo '012007') y VentasUSD (float), como hago para obtener a través de una consulta registro a registro de las ventas del periodo y las del mismo periodo pero año anterior.

Comment: Seria bueno entonces que actualices tu pregunta y pongas un ejemplo de los datos como los tienes en este momento, y que resultado es el que esperas de la consulta. Con esto puedes aclarar mucho mas tu necesidad.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta lo siguiente, primero estoy haciendo una sub-consulta filtrada por los años que se desean visualizar y adicionando una columna que se llama 'Mes'. Luego se agrupan los datos por ese mes. Ahora bien, para obtener los valores de las columnas para cada año, se realizan las sumatorias de esas columnas condicionadas con un CASE.

```
SELECT 
    Mes
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN RIGHT(IdPeriodo, 4) = '2016' THEN ValorNetoUSD ELSE 0 END) USD
    ,MIN(IdPeriodo) AS Periodo  
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN RIGHT(IdPeriodo, 4) = '2017' THEN ValorNetoUSD ELSE 0 END) USDAA
    ,MAX(IdPeriodo) AS PeriodoAA
FROM 
(
    SELECT IdPeriodo, LEFT(IdPeriodo, 2) AS Mes, ValorNetoUSD
    FROM AT2020_DWH.dbo.FctVentaMensual 
    WHERE RIGHT(IdPeriodo, 4) IN ('2016','2017')
) VM
GROUP BY
    Mes
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. Soy bastante principiante en SQL. Tu ejemplo no me ayuda mucho a darme cuenta como tendría que resolverlo, o en que me ayuda lo que me planteas. De todas formas, muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya intentaste ejecutar este script en tu base de datos?. Que resultado obtuviste?. Para poderte colaborar de una mejor manera.

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo el inner join al revés, intenta hacer el add -1 a la inversa

```
SELECT VM1.valornetousd AS USD, 
       VM1.idperiodo    AS Periodo, 
       VM2.valornetousd AS USDAA, 
       VM2.idperiodo    AS PeriodoAA 
FROM   at2020_dwh.dbo.fctventamensual AS VM1 
       INNER JOIN at2020_dwh.dbo.fctventamensual AS VM2 
               ON Dateadd(year, -1, CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(VM1.idperiodo, 2) + '/01/'+ RIGHT(VM1.idperiodo,4))) = CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(VM2.idperiodo, 2) + '/01/' + RIGHT(VM2.idperiodo, 4));
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. Esa consulta me devuelve la mismos registros. Obtengo registros duplicados.

Comment: Muy extraño, acabo de intentar tu consulta original con datos de prueba, y si funciona. Es posible que tus tablas, por ser de Data warehouse, no esten normalizadas y tengan registros repetidos en funcion a una dimension. Mi sugerencia sería que revises la tabla ´FctVentaMensual´ y veas si no hay duplicados en la misma, o bien si hace falta que filtres por algun otro campo.